# Uniform continuity and bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

**Problem**

If the sequence ${f_n}\subset C[a,b]$ is **uniformly continuous**, it is **bounded**.

If the sequence ${f_n}\subset C[a,b]$ is **bounded**, it is **uniformly continuous**.

Maybe someone can give me some hints for this? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) Take a sequence of constant functions that diverge to infinity

2) Take a sequence $f_n (t) =[(b-t)(b-a)^{-1} ]^n $